# sql query takes too much time with one more where clause

Tags: sql-server

I'm using sql server 2012 for asp.net.

the original code takes about 2 seconds..

```
select sl.pnum, st.lastEntered, sum(sl.idx) from products p
join spartlist sl on (sl.idx=p.pnumidx)
join shipping_T sht on p.shippingIdx = sht.idx
join sales_T st on sht.shippingOutIdx = st.idx
join itemFrom_T ift on st.custIdx = ift.custidx
where ift.idx not in (1, 2, 19, 33, 34, 44, 45, 46, 47, 17)
group by sl.pnum, st.lastEntered
order by st.lastEntered desc
```

and adding one more where clause makes it executing over 10 minutes!

```
select sl.pnum, st.lastEntered, sum(sl.idx) from products p
join spartlist sl on (sl.idx=p.pnumidx)
join shipping_T sht on p.shippingIdx = sht.idx
join sales_T st on sht.shippingOutIdx = st.idx
join itemFrom_T ift on st.custIdx = ift.custidx
where ift.idx not in (1, 2, 19, 33, 34, 44, 45, 46, 47, 17) and 
st.lastentered > dateadd(wk, -4, getdate())
group by sl.pnum, st.lastEntered
order by st.lastEntered desc
```

someone could give me advice what's taking so long and how to solve it,
and also I have to write queries base on this and what is a good practice..
to practice query optimization?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that there's no index on `st.lastentered`; thus a table scan has to be completed. A good start would be supplying the query plans for your 2 queries.

Comment: Include execution plans for both queries and share here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: @Larnu Hi Larnu, thank you for your help.. but if you don't mind, could you elaborate that in the answer? I am not sure if I understand what you're saying.

Comment: Have a look at the link that @Cool_Br33ze provided. On your execution plan pane, right click it and select `Show Execution Plan XML`. Then paste that into the link and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another little improvement would be to create a variable for the date you are comparing against.

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = dateadd(wk, -4, getdate())
```

and then in your select.....

```
..
st.lastentered > @d
```

This saves GETDATE and DATEADD being called for each row.

Comment: OMG. This was it. After changing this it takes two seconds!! Thanks!!!!!

Comment: Glad to have been of asistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the query with an execution plan in SQL Server, with that you can check what is taking so long in your query.
Might be a missing or incorrect index, or anything else which is the result of the execution plan.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it. Didn't know about execution plans.